# True/False expression from columns in different tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to count number of rows which fullfil the criteria thus create a true/false expression as a filter from two columns from different tables.

```
CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('Fact Table'),
'Fact Table'[Column1] <> "ARP1" ||
'Dim Table'[Column2] <> "DK01")
```

Tried with `|| RELATED ('Dim Table'[Column2] ) <> "DK01"` but PBI claims that I dont have either relationship (I have where Dim is one Fact is many) or does not exist (exist because even intellisense suggested that column). Any idea how to overcome that?

Comment: Why are you counting rows when you want to end up with a true/false expression?

Comment: I want to check how many rows does fullfil the criteria - are different than `'Fact Table'[Column1] <> "ARP1"` OR `'Dim Table'[Column2] <> "DK01"`. What's the another approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        'Fact Table'
        ,NOT OR([Column1] = "ARP1", [Column2] = "DK01") 
)
```

Comment: `[Column2]` is from another table (dimension). Is there a way to include that or I'd need to bring it to the fact table? I wanted to avoid it but seems like necessary?

Comment: oh... I see now )

Comment: how your tables are linked?

Comment: dimension (one), to fact (many)

Comment: if its not possible this way, i'll just join the tables in native query and retrieve this column to the fact table but considering that fact table has millions of rows its not the best to bring anything I need there thus denormalizing it slowly but surely.. haha

Comment: which column in facts is equal to dim [Column2] ? you are trying to filter facts with value  "DK01". What is the column name for facts where you can have "DK01" value? I'll come back to SO in 2-3 hours. If you will not solve the issue we can continue then.